# Angular orderBy - Undefined values always at the end (Strings)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sql-order-by

I'd like to know how to use the angular orderBy filter in combination with a custom function for sorting having undefined values always at the end.

I've done the following for sorting numbers:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | handleEmptyValues(sortOptions):sortOptions.reverse)">
```

.. and in the controller:

```
handleEmptyValues (sortOptions) {

    const appendLast = sortOptions.reverse
        ? Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
        : Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    return (item) => (item.property) || appendLast;
}
```

How can I do the same for strings?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind items with `undefined` and `''` (empty string) sorted with the same weight you could try a different approach, i.e. replace `undefined` with `''`:

1. In the model directly **or**
2. Using a custom angular `filter` (see [AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09))